# Multi-character delimiter with STRING_SPLIT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split, delimiter

I want to split values based on multiple values like `!` and `%`, operators, but `STRING_SPLIT` only allows 1-character delimiters.

My string is like this:

```
99001316 - ABCD 250 ML!%!%99001234 - CDEF 500 ML!%!%99001995 - OWEW 50 ML
```

And what I want is to separate the numeric and text value.
When I do this:

```
SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@x, '%',1)
```

I'm getting

| value |
| --- |
| 99001234 - ABCD 250 ML! |
| ! |
| 99001230 - CDEF 500 ML! |
| ! |
| 99001995 - OWEW 50 ML |

And what I want is

| value | string |
| --- | --- |
| 99001234 | ABCD 250 ML! |
| 99001230 | CDEF 500 ML! |
| 99001995 | OWEW 50 ML |

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question and add the desired results

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: For posterity, [Dealing with the single-character delimiter in STRING_SPLIT](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4940/dealing-with-the-singlecharacter-delimiter-in-sql-servers-stringsplit-function/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) and, more generally, [Splitting strings](https://sqlblog.org/split).

Answer (score 4):

One option is to parse the string via JSON.  You may notice the delimiter of `'!%!%'`

```
Declare @X varchar(max) = '99001316 - ABCD 250 ML!%!%99001230 - CDEF 500 ML!%!%99001395 - OWEW 50 ML'


Select Value  = rtrim(left(value,charindex('-',Value+'-')-1))
      ,String = ltrim(substring(value,charindex('-',Value+'-')+1,len(Value)))
 From  OpenJSON( '["'+replace(string_escape(@X,'json'),'!%!%','","')+'"]' )
```

**Resutls**

```
Value       String
99001316    ABCD 250 ML
99001230    CDEF 500 ML
99001395    OWEW 50 ML
```

Comment: Thank you so much @John!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @tokens NVARCHAR(max) = N'99001316 - ABCD 250 ML!%!%99001234 - CDEF 500 ML!%!%99001995 - OWEW 50 ML';

WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT value AS token 
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(@tokens,'!%!%','%') , '%')
)
SELECT * 
, LEFT(token, pos - 1) AS [value]
, RIGHT(token, LEN(token) - pos - 1) AS [string]
FROM rs
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('-', token)) AS t(pos);
```

**Output**

```
+------------------------+-----+-----------+-------------+
|         token          | pos |   value   |   string    |
+------------------------+-----+-----------+-------------+
| 99001316 - ABCD 250 ML |  10 | 99001316  | ABCD 250 ML |
| 99001234 - CDEF 500 ML |  10 | 99001234  | CDEF 500 ML |
| 99001995 - OWEW 50 ML  |  10 | 99001995  | OWEW 50 ML  |
+------------------------+-----+-----------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some more ideas

```
DECLARE @X VARCHAR(MAX) = '99001316 - ABCD 250 ML!%!%99001230 - CDEF 500 ML!%!%99001395 - OWEW 50 ML';

WITH s1 AS  (
            SELECT      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS ord1
                        , s1.value
            FROM        STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(@X, '!%!%', '|'), '|') s1
            ),
s2 AS       (
            SELECT      s1.ord1
                        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s1.ord1 ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS ord2
                        , s2.value
            FROM        s1
            CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(s1.value, ' - ', '|'), '|') s2
            )
SELECT      MAX(CASE WHEN s2.ord2 = 1 THEN s2.value END) AS id
            , MAX(CASE WHEN s2.ord2 = 2 THEN s2.value END) AS text
FROM        s2
GROUP BY    s2.ord1
```

You can include `ordinal` column with `STRING_SPLIT` on Azure (passing `1` in 3-rd parameter) and remove the `ROW_NUMBER` usage for both `ord` columns above.